# How can I save a photo into a folder with mdm zinc in flash?

Tags: image, actionscript-3, flash, mdm, mdm-zinc

So far I have this code which uploads the photo

```
mdm.Dialogs.BrowseFile.filterList = "Images|*.bmp;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.png;*.gif";
function showPrompt(eventObj:MouseEvent):void {
var f:String = mdm.Dialogs.BrowseFile.show();
if (f!="" && f!=false) {
    l1.source = f;
    addChild(l1);
}
```

**My question is how can I save the photo into another folder?** 
for example something like:

```
mdm.FileSystem.BinaryFile.setDataBA();
mdm.FileSystem.BinaryFile.writeData("c:\\myimage.jpg");
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [`ImageAdv` class in MDM's Livedocs](http://www.multidmedia.com/support/livedocs/4.0/class.php?action=class&class=ImageAdv)

`ImageAdv` contains methods like `loadJpg` and `saveJpg`, probably this will help you.